# Swipe with Activity:- Resource Not Found Exception

Tags: android, exception, android-pageradapter

I am trying to swipe some part of the screen. I use PageAdapter for this. In swiping part I have three activity
1. ShowMap
2. ShowAddress
3. ShowContact

I am trying to getting id of layout of ShowMap Activity but it's showing resource not found exception.  Here is my code of **MyPageAdapter** class

```
 public class anyclass extends Activity{
    private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        public int getCount(){
            return 3;
        }

        public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            int resId = 0;
            switch (position) {
            case 0: 
                resId = showHotelContact();             
                break;
            case 1:
                resId = showHotelAddress();         
                break;              
            case 2:     
                resId = showHotelMap();             
                break;      
            }

            View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
            ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
            return view;
        }

    }

    public int showHotelMap()
    {

        Intent bookIntent = new Intent();     
        bookIntent.setClass(HotelMap.this,ShowMap.class);
        startActivityForResult(bookIntent,RESID);

        return RESID;
    }
    public int showHotelAddress()
    {
        int resId;
        resId = R.layout.hoteladdress;
        return resId;
    }
    public int showHotelContact()
    {
        int resId;
        resId = R.layout.hotelcontact;
        return resId;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            RESID = data.getIntExtra("SelectedBook", resultCode);
        }
    }
   }
```

I need id of showMap layout and i am trying to return it to my PageAdapter but it's showing an exception. 
And here is the code of **ShowMap activity**.

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hotelmap);

               int  resId = R.layout.hotelmap;
           Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
           returnIntent.putExtra("SelectedBook",resId);
           setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);        
           finish();

        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setStreetView(true);
        MapController mc = mapView.getController();
        double lat = Double.parseDouble("48.85827758964043"); // latitude
        double lon = Double.parseDouble("2.294543981552124"); // longitude
        GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6), (int)(lon * 1E6));
        mc.animateTo(geoPoint);
        mc.setZoom(15);
        mapView.invalidate();
        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

   }
```

Here is my **Logcat**.

```
 12-31 13:14:26.740: E/AndroidRuntime(31140): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
    12-31 13:14:26.740: E/AndroidRuntime(31140):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1104)
    12-31 13:14:26.740: E/AndroidRuntime(31140):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2342)
    12-31 13:14:26.740: E/AndroidRuntime(31140):    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:943)
    12-31 13:14:26.740: E/AndroidRuntime(31140):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
    12-31 13:14:26.740: E/AndroidRuntime(31140):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    12-31 13:14:26.740: E/AndroidRuntime(31140):    at com..HotelMap$MyPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(HotelMap.java:52)
    12-31 13:14:26.740: E/AndroidRuntime(31140):    at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.instantiateItem(PagerAdapter.java:110)
    12-31 13:14:26.740: E/AndroidRuntime(31140):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:801)
    12-31 13:14:26.740: E/AndroidRuntime(31140):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:930)
    12-31 13:14:26.740: E/AndroidRuntime(31140):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:881)
```

Comment: What are u doing in `showHotelMap()`?? What is the value of `RESID`?

Comment: In onCreate method remove the finish() and try

Comment: @Faizan:in resId , I am trying to get layout id and trying to return to pageAdapter class to show this map.

Comment: @Taruni: no it's not working. it show same exception: Resource not foundException

Comment: Your structure is not workable.

Comment: @Faizan:then how can i do this? can you arrange it or tell me how to do this? where i am wrong? is ma i getting resource id or not?

Answer (score 3):

```
startActivityForResult(bookIntent,RESID);
```

I guess this is an Async Call. Program will not wait until the activity the starting activity finishes and returns the result, rather it will just execute this line and move on to the next line. So that is why `RESID` returned by the method `showHotelMap()` is **0**.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this it may help you..

```
public class TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private TabHost mTabHost;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private HashMap<String, TabInfo> mapTabInfo = new HashMap<String, TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.TabInfo>();
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    private class TabInfo {
         private String tag;
         private Class<?> clss;
         private Bundle args;
         private Fragment fragment;
         TabInfo(String tag, Class<?> clazz, Bundle args) {
             this.tag = tag;
             this.clss = clazz;
             this.args = args;
         }

    }

    class TabFactory implements TabContentFactory {

        private final Context mContext;


        public TabFactory(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        /** (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory#createTabContent(java.lang.String)
         */
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View v = new View(mContext);
            v.setMinimumWidth(0);
            v.setMinimumHeight(0);
            return v;
        }

    }
    /** (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Inflate the layout
        setContentView(R.layout.tabs_viewpager_layout);
        // Initialise the TabHost
        this.initialiseTabHost(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab")); //set the tab as per the saved state
        }
        // Intialise ViewPager
        this.intialiseViewPager();
    }

    /** (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag()); //save the tab selected
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    /**
     * Initialise ViewPager
     */
    private void intialiseViewPager() {

        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab1Fragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab2Fragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab3Fragment.class.getName()));
        this.mPagerAdapter  = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        //
        this.mViewPager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        this.mViewPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
        this.mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * Initialise the Tab Host
     */
    private void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {
        mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();
        TabInfo tabInfo = null;
        TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("Tab 1"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab1", Tab1Fragment.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
        TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("Tab 2"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab2", Tab2Fragment.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
        TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("Tab 3"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab3", Tab3Fragment.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
        // Default to first tab
        //this.onTabChanged("Tab1");
        //
        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * Add Tab content to the Tabhost
     * @param activity
     * @param tabHost
     * @param tabSpec
     * @param clss
     * @param args
     */
    private static void AddTab(TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) {
        // Attach a Tab view factory to the spec
        tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    }

    /** (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener#onTabChanged(java.lang.String)
     */
    public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
        //TabInfo newTab = this.mapTabInfo.get(tag);
        int pos = this.mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
        this.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener#onPageScrolled(int, float, int)
     */
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
            int positionOffsetPixels) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener#onPageSelected(int)
     */
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener#onPageScrollStateChanged(int)
     */
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Otherwise get help from the given link..

http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/android-tabs-viewpager-swipe-able-tabs-ftw/